# why am I getting 502 Bad gateway trying to do reverse proxy sub path

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, gogs

I am trying to reverse proxy sub path , the domain https://raspberrypi.local works fine but https://raspberrypi.local/gogs/ is return ing 502 Bad Gateway.

This is the file: /etc/nginx/sites-available/gogs
**Updated: 12-10-2016**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name raspberrypi.local;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/localcerts/raspberrypi.local.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/localcerts/raspberrypi.local.key;

# taken out from location
# proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    location /gogs/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    }
}

# Redirect HTTP request to HTTPS

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name raspberrypi.local;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

the /home/git/gogs/log/gogs.log shows that

```
2016/09/12 17:35:40 [I] Git Version: 2.1.4
2016/09/12 17:35:40 [I] Run Mode: Production
2016/09/12 17:35:43 [I] Listen: https://0.0.0.0:3000/gogs
```

Comment: Have you tried using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in the `proxy_pass` statement?

Comment: My raspberrypi.local is on 192.168.1.45 so you mean that instead of 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: You seem to be proxy passing to service 3000 on the same machine as nginx. So localhost or 127.0.0.1 is the correct address for the same machine.

Comment: @RichardSmith : I updated the `nginx config` for `gogs` now it prompted for SSL certificate but then later displayed blank page: `https://raspberrypi.local:3000/gogs/` but on 3000 port .

Comment: It's working correctly then. Is your certificate self-signed or have you obtained it from a provider?